# Setting IIS 7 to allow outbound requests in Medium Trust mode

Tags: iis-7

I am trying to emulate GoDaddy's environment so I can do pre deployment tests.

The default Medium Trust settings dont allow outbound http, but godaddy has made an exception to their rules. How do I make the same exception on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send them an email asking for their trust template.  They may provide it for you.  Then go to your framework folder (c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework...) and in your root web.config file at the top are the trust settings.  Define a new template pointing to the template they provide, and then make sure to call the template.  It's straight forward right in that section at the top.